# Laravel blade @includeWhen gives me Undefined variable error

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-6

When I do like this

```
@includeWhen($category, 'modules.breadcrumbs')
```

I got error

> Undefined variable: category

So I can do it only using the old way

```
@isset ($category)
     @include('modules.breadcrumbs')
@endisset
```

But I cannot understand why?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I understand problem. This is the solution

```
@includeWhen( isset($category) , 'modules.sidebar')
```